# How to paste data to excel table and keeping the values parallel to table key?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I work with excel files its very often to insert new data to a table, but copy and pasting each value one by one the be in the same row with the key table takes a lot of time and effort. Is there any way to do it without doing it one by one?

I'll try to explain my problem with a simple example:
This is (for example) the table I am working on-

[Main table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNv3W.png)

and lets say that I have found data from some data base that has 4 number that are already in the Main table:

[New data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM2Tv.png)

My final goal is to have them inside the main table and having the final table:

[Final Main table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcZVd.png)

What I have done in this case is locating each phone number from the new data and then inserting the ID in the same line.

Comment: If more than one or two pages often better to use a database and follow (most of) Codd's rules. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules Specifically you need unique ID and insert or update based on that ID.

Comment: @oldfred What do you mean when you say pages? In my case the table is being modified always and a Database for it will take too many time and recourses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Vlookup function in Excel to do this.

[image]

Where you need to input the new value (SomeID) you need to enter a formula instead. You can find documentation on VLOOKUP [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

[image]

In the example above, A6 refers to the value you want to "lookup". You should lookup a value in the same row normally. A6 in this example is 13313802.

The next argument in the Formula is the new table of information to check your value against. The cell references are surrounded in $ absolute references so when you reuse the functionality in the rest of the cells in column D, the look up table reference doesn't move.

The next value is "2". This refers to the column that should be returned to the cell if the value is found in the table.

The final value is "False". If you use "True" an approximate match will found (you don't want this).

It's also important to note, in order for this to work ensure your new Data is ordered A-Z beforehand or the Vlookup won't find your value.

Comment: might aswell include IFERROR to remove N/As

Comment: Thanks Dom. some questions:
1) What should be oredered A-Z, the keys(Phone) or the values(someID) in me new data?
2) I ran the function succesfully, but is there a way to run this function on all of the Keys in the new data? something that won't require me to run it each time?

Comment: 1) The values you are checking against need to be ordered. In your case it's the "new data" should be ordered by column 1. In my example (where new data is in range G5:H9 you need to order that data by the values in column 1 (G5).

Comment: 2) I am not sure what this means, in the example, it looks up all the values in the new data already. If you mean, can it refer to all the "new data" you keep adding. Then yes, you need to change the function to take into account more rows at the bottom where you will add new data. In my example, if you were pasting more new data, you would extend the function $G$5:$H$100 add as many as you want...